# Azure SQL Database DevOps Release pipeline returns Error CREATE DATABASE permission denied

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database

I have created build and release pipelines for Azure SQL Database according to these [instructions](https://microsoft.github.io/PartsUnlimited/iac/200.2x-IaC-CDAzureSQLdbwithVSTSandVS.html).

I am able to publish my database project directly from Visual Studio.
My Build pipeline works without problems.
However on release pipeline I am getting the following error:

> Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 262, Level 14, State 1, Line 1 CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
>   Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
>   CREATE DATABASE [$(Datab
>   aseName)] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;

Any idea what I may be doing wrong or how to find where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feeling a bit stupid right about now. I finally found how to debug the pipeline (variable system.debug = true) and it was telling me that it can't find the database defined. Which I had mistyped. 
However the error without the debugging option was NOT helpful :D So if anyone is getting this error they should recheck connection information.

Comment: Really thanks for sharing your solution here, if so, would you please [Accept your solution as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) ? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)